# por que no se modifica el array inicial con este programa?

Tags: python, array, bucle-for, bucles

estaba haciendo un programa en el que parto de un array random y quiero modificar ese array.pero cuando corro el siguiente programa,mi array de arranque no cambia.

```
B=np.random.randn(4,4,10)


N=4
J=4
T=10


for t in range (T-1):
for i in range (N-1): 
    for j in range (J-1):
        B[i,j,t+1]=B[i,j,t]-( B[i+1,j,t]+B[i,j+1,t] -2*B[i,j,t]-2*B[i,j,t]+B[i-1,j,t]+B[i,j-1,t] )
        
        
print(B)
```

alguna idea? grcias!

Comment: Acabo de ejecutar tu código. Lo imprimí antes y después, y el array si se modifica. No veo cuál es el problema.

Comment: por qué dices que no se modifica?? ahí claramente se ve una asignación y debe de modificarse, Tu problema no puede ser reproducido y tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Para próximas preguntas lee [ask]

Comment: Además de lo antes mencionado, tu `for i in range (N-1):` está mal identado. NO está dentro del for de más arriba como deberia.